# How to stop overflowing file descriptors in C

Tags: system, file-descriptor, buffer-overflow

I am writing a message to a file descriptor that is 88kb. The file descriptor on my linux system only can hold 64kb. Once the data gets put on the file descriptor it gets read and piped into a tcp connection.

How do i know if I can write more data to the file descriptor, meaning the file descriptor is empty? I need a function that blocks until the file descriptor is empty or at least can return a value letting me know how data I can safely write to the file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

I think [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) is probably what you want.  With the right arguments, you can arrange
for it to block until your file descriptor is ready for your I/O operations.

Your question is worded a little strangely, though, since we don't generally refer to 
file descriptors as having a capacity, or being "empty".  It sounds like maybe
you're talking about a file descriptor that represents one endpoint of a pipe,
and it's the pipe (not the file descriptor) that has a capacity of 64 KB.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me more like the OP is trying to send a datagram (AF_UNIX or AF_INET/UDP) larger than the configured maximum packet size.  Other possibilities are pipes and FIFOs, which have maximum atomic write sizes; the fix here is to do multiple writes, and successive writes will block until there is room for them in the pipe/FIFO.